# linked server compares between Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

We   are doing a migration from Oracle 10g to SQL Server 2014.  Once I set up the linked Server connection in SQL Server to the Oracle DB will I be able to run a statement like the following:

```
select * from linkedservername...schema.table
except
select * from Servername.database.schema.table
```

Not all queries will be this easy as I'll have to do some data manipulation on the oracle side.  Will I need to use Oracle syntax for that or once I have the linked server set up will everything be in T-SQL for querying purposes?

Thanks

Comment: are you using sql server migration assistant for Oracle, if not you should consider this. How big is the schema and data volume? I'd advise using ANSI or as close as possible syntax, but yes assume you need to use Oracle if the query is going to be initiated on the oracle server - easy to test like select col1 vs select col1 from dual

Comment: Data volume is around 4.5 million rows for one of the tables.....  What we are actually building is a new model to cleanse data and I was going to use this to actually compare the new model matches the old model in the destination DB.